# Bad GFCI or did I wire it wrong?

Tags: electrical, gfci

I just installed a Hubbel GFCI socket and when I turned the circuit breaker back on the GFCI green and red led lights went on and the reset button would not stay in.

The ground wires are pigtailed and connected to the ground screw on the metal box.

The line cable leads are connected to the appropriate colored line screws on the gfci

The existing load cable pair  are connected to the appropriate load screws on the gfci.

Don’t know if I have a bad GFCI or something is wrong with my my wiring.

Could another unknown GFCI device on that came circuit be causing this problem

Any ideas what might be wrong?

Comment: "The ground wires are pigtailed and connected to the ground screw on the metal box." Unless I am mistaken, there is only one ground wire on these sockets. Hot and white for load and line, and ground. Also, make sure the metal box is actually grounded too. If someone screwed it on timber and did not use a shield that is a problem.

Comment: @DrunkenCodeMonkey -- eh? what's this "shield" you're talking about?

Comment: The metallic EM shield you put around the wires in the wall to bring the earth signal to an outlet not grounded to the structure. The point was that binding the earth ground wire to the metal casing behind the outlet doesn't do anything if the outlet casing isn't grounded. You see this often when old 2 prongs outlets are replaced.

Answer (score 11):

Always pause in your installation after you have fitted the `LINE` wires, but before you have fitted any `LOAD` wires. Power up and run the GFCI through its paces.

This clears a number of problems, including

- getting supply and downline wires confused
- accidentally attaching to the `LOAD` terminals
- shorts and other problems with the downline wiring
- having an *actual ground fault* somewhere downline

If the GFCI works without anything on the `LOAD` line, then you know that if problems emerge after adding a set of wires to `LOAD`, this is a problem there, and can troubleshoot accordingly.

Another GFCI device on a different circuit cannot cause this.  Another GFCI upstream on this circuit would cause this GFCI to go dark entirely.

Answer (score 6):

Try removing the load wires. If the GFCI will reset with just the outlet powered there is a wiring fault or a device down stream that is causing the problem.

Comment: ...thanks for the suggestion the GFCI was able to reset after the load wires were removed.

Comment: I spent an hour trying to find any outlets downstream from the newly installed GFCI but cannot.  The reason I installed the outlet was to connect a run of UF to it to power a pole lantern.  There was no problem with that load.   Will continue to try to solve the mystery of the downstream outlets